# ElectronJS quickstart: Cannot connect to target localhost:9222 and no window opens

Tags: electron, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

Any ideas?  I have ElectronJS installed. Netstat checked: no running 9222 port. Code and configs seem correct. Restarted computer with no chrome or edge running. Still same problem.

There are similar questions on StackOverflow but not relevant because not with ElectronJS.(they run localServer or jsDebugTools)

Here's my terminal:

```
PS C:\dev\electronjs\electrOverstand>  C:; cd 'C:\dev\electronjs\electrOverstand'; ${env:NODE_OPTIONS}=' --require C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp\vscode-js-debug-bootloader.js '; ${env:VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS}=':::{"inspectorIpc":"\\\\.\\pipe\\node-cdp.10828-40734b62-35.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node.exe","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"C:\\Users\\Hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\node-debug-callback-96eaf51f02052f43"}'; & 'C:\dev\electronjs\electrOverstand/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd' '.' '--remote-debugging-port=9222'    
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56082/71af553d-93a4-4be4-b3db-1ef924afc662
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
(node:12048) ExperimentalWarning: queueMicrotask() is experimental.

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56088/22b2663a-82eb-4aa7-8fe9-f2a82b324eb6
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

Here's the code if anyone cares to take a look: https://github.com/pashute/electrOverstand/tree/develop

The launch.json is as follows:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Main + renderer",
            "configurations": ["Main", "Renderer"],
            "stopAll": true
        }
    ],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Renderer",
            "port": 9222,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Main",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
            },
            "args": [".", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"],
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "console": "integratedTerminal" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I get:

[image: Error cannot connect to localhost:9222]